# How could I label the intersection point as `O`?

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]Moreover, how may I colour the two angles `AOA'` and `BOB'` in two different colours?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{color}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(6,5){B} 
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,5){A^{'}}
    \tkzDefPoint(6,0){B^{'}}
    \tkzDrawSegment(A^{'},B^{'})
    \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A,B,A^{'},B^{'})
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,A^{'},B^{'}) 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your question is how to generate the intersection point automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the intersection of the 2 segments and save it as a point. Then color the point.

Also, as commented by @Harish, you can color the angles. Since we want the point `O` over the other parts, its code is at the end.

```
\tkzInterLL(A,B)(A^{'},B^{'}) 
\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red](O)
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(6,5){B} 
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,5){A^{'}}
    \tkzDefPoint(6,0){B^{'}}
    \tkzDrawSegment(A^{'},B^{'})
    \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](A,B,A^{'},B^{'})
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,A^{'},B^{'}) 
    \tkzInterLL(A,B)(A^{'},B^{'}) 
    \tkzGetPoint{O}
%% colored angles
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1 cm,draw=red,fill=blue!40](A^{'},O,A) 
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1 cm,draw=blue,fill=olive!40](B^{'},O,B)
    \tkzDrawPoint[color=black,size=5mm,fill=white](O)
%% label for point O
    \tkzLabelPoints[yshift=8mm](O)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what about the intersections library? Do I need to load it?

Comment: @TroyWoo, I'm just using your code. I'll complete it.

Comment: I learned...though I am not the PO...

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-eucl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 2, nodesep = -0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.4,-1.3)(3.5,2.3)
  \pstGeonode(-1,-1){A}(3,2){B}(-1,2){A'}(3,-1){B'}
  \pstInterLL{A}{B}{B'}{A'}{O}
  \pstLineAB{A}{B}
  \pstLineAB{A'}{B'}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you don't want the ends of the line segments to stretch beyond the points, remove `nodesep = -0.5`.

Comment: @SvendTveskaeg Your answer matches with what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reproduction of Sigur's nice graph, using MetaPost (inside a LuaLaTeX program) and some other parameters instead.

The intersection point is very easily obtained with MetaPost, thanks to the very handy `whatever` macro. I've also made use of the `buidcycle` and the `anglebetween` macros (this one comes from the MetaFun format) for the angles and their colouring, and created a macro of my own to draw the "empty" dot where the intersection takes place.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math, xcolor}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
  vardef drawemptydot (expr z, r) = 
    save circle; path circle; circle = fullcircle scaled r shifted z; 
    unfill circle; draw circle ;
  enddef;
  beginfig(0);
    % Settings
    u = cm ; % The general unit
    pair A, Ap, B, Bp, O ; A = origin ; B = (6, 5)*u ; Ap = (0, 5)*u ; Bp = (6, 0)*u ;
    O = whatever[A, B] = whatever[Ap, Bp] ;
    % Fine tuning (angles)
    path angle_OAAp ; angle_OAAp = anglebetween(O--A, O--Ap, "") ;
    path angle_OBBp ; angle_OBBp = anglebetween(O--B, O--Bp, "") ;
    % Fillings and drawings angles
    fill buildcycle(O--A, angle_OAAp, O--Ap) withcolor \mpcolor{olive!40} ; 
    draw angle_OAAp withcolor red ;
    fill buildcycle(O--B, angle_OBBp, O--Bp) withcolor \mpcolor{blue!40}  ; 
    draw angle_OBBp withcolor red ;
    % Drawing segments
    draw A -- B ; draw = Ap -- Bp ;
    % The dots
    for P = A, B, Ap, Bp: drawdot P withpen pencircle scaled 3bp ; endfor ;
    drawemptydot(O, 3bp) ;
    % The labels
    label.bot("$O$", O) ; label.lft("$A$", A) ; label.rt("$B$", B) ;
    label.rt("$B'$", Bp) ; label.lft("$A'$", Ap) ;
    % Bounding box enlarged (prevents labels cropping at the extremities of the graph)
    setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 3bp ;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is BRILLIANT! A perfect set up. This helps me enormously.